# Left 4 Dead 2 (Beta) with fglrx slow

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx, steam

I have Xubuntu 13.04 amd64. I have switchable AMD GPUs with 6650M as dedicated, I have succesfully installed the very latest fglrx from AMD website (with package generation for good integration with dpkg).
My dedicated GPU laughs at L4D2 on Windows with maximum settings, but now on Linux is fairly slow (it's playable but I had to downscale settings), the fps is about a maximum of 30 and sometimes it hangs for a bit.

Is it because:

- fglrx is slow
- l4d2 is still beta so when it becomes final they will fix it and will become faster
- not my dedicated gpu is used

What is the answer and anyways how can I check if my dedicated gpu is used for games? In catalyst control center I set use the more powerful gpu in the switchable section.
Hint: I play Dota2 too with native resolution and high settings and that is very well playable.

Answer (score 0):

Use oibaf PPA for the latest open source drivers instead; fglrx has a lot of issues for gaming in general. Open source drivers will give you significantly better performance and fix bugs.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y; sudo apt-get purge fglrx; sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

If you were using xorg-edgers for the latest PPA, do remove that first:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge; sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
```

Comment: Thanks! Result: Counter Strike: slightly slower, L4D2: better (!), Dota2: major slowdown... I need Windows or nvidia hardware I guess. :/

Comment: The thing with AMD at the moment is that they didn't start caring about AMD Linux drivers until July 30th when Marek Olšák was hired to work on the open source drivers full time. Since then, he's submitted major amounts of patches which have drastically improved AMD on Linux. They don't care that much about Catalyst though, apparently. It might take them until around Ubuntu 14.04 to reach better performance than Catalyst on Windows.